# What locator should I use in Protractor?

Tags: css, angularjs, selenium, xpath, protractor

[image: test screenshot]

I am testing some angular page as you can see in the screenshot. I tried my best to find the proper locators to select a value from the dropdown list but failed. In Java Selenium, it used to work as `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@role='option']//contains(text(),'"+valToBeSelected+"')].click()` by xpath. What should I use in protractor?

Here is the screenshot for elements sources, I tried to copy the source code but it seems to be very large. Sorry I have to take three screenshots, please use the *green commend line* as the separator.

[image]
continue
[image]
continue
[image]

Then a list of as `<div role="options" ...>China</div>`, `<div role="options" ...>Chad</div>` etc.,

Answer (score 1):

Click the `a` element to open up the select box:

```
element(by.xpath("//a[span = 'Please select your country of residence']")).click();
```

Then, locate the desired dropdown element by text:

```
element(by.xpath("//li[@role='option' and .//div[. = 'Algeria']]")).click();
```

There are certainly other options/locators here, but checking and relying on the elements texts would, at least, have a readability bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse over those HTML elements until you find the dropdown blue'd out, and grab a selector using that blue'd out area.

From what I can see, it looks like 'ui-select-choices-group' maaaay be the one.

So you'd use a CSS shorthand selector:

```
var dropdown = $('.ui-select-choices-group');
```

Then to access values in in:

```
dropdown.$('[value="Algeria"].click();
// Or
$('.ui-select-choices-group').$('[value="Algeria"]').click()
```

See if that works. This selector may be right, but it is a bit hard to tell for me without having both the HTML and the browser open, and mousing over the html elements in the code page to see what gets highlighted.

Comment: Thank you. `.ui-select-choices-row` is what gets highlighted.  If I wish to write a generic selectFromDropdownList function as the following `var list = element.all(listLocator); for(var option in list){
   option.getText().then(function(text){ if(text.equals(content)){option.click();}});` . Is `.ui-select-choices-row` something I should use to define `listLocator` here?

Comment: `$('.ui-select-choices-row').$([value='Algeria']).click();` gave `ERROR: UnknownError: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: Sorry, I had some syntax wrong in the second selector. How about:
$('.ui-select-choices-row').$('[value"'Algeria"]').click();
Note the placement of the single and double quotes in the second part.

Comment: the second part does not seem working :( `ERROR: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("[value=\"Algeria\"]")`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what selector you'd need to get the actual value out then. Looking at the html example you dropped in at the end, I imagine there is a long list of `<div role="options" ...>CountryName</div>`. That should be accessible by value, but if not you may try something more like `$$('[role="options"]').get(2)`, and just hope the order doesn't change.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. The weired part is, so far everything written in selenium works fine, but not protractor, but the purpose of protractor is to test angular sites right? From the scripts you can tell this is a typical angular site.